# How to Change the Color of the Last item in ListView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Custom list and Adapter in xamarin how do i change the color of the last item in the listview

here is what i have tried but did not work

```
if (view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1).Text == "Add Profile") {
                view.FindViewById (Resource.Id.linearLayout1).SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Aqua);
                Console.WriteLine ("LastItem");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the list item view background color by override the GetView method under your adapter class.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.From(this.context).Inflate('Your layout axml', parent, false);
    }

    convertView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Aqua);

    return convertView;
}
```